# Prism v4 Difference between WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, prism-4

We are designing a Line of Business application which will use Prism.

The application will use web services and all the business logic will be encapsulated behind the web services.

What we are wondering is for a standard data entry business application will there be any difference between Silverlight and WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you use standard controls,use MVVM, avoid COM, other windows dependent stuff, it should be OK but it depends:

1. Basically WPF and Silverlight have different set of controls e.g. Silverlight has great DataFrom entry which is not available with WPF or even simple BusyIndicator. In most cases if control exsist in WPF it's in Silverlight but there are few that are not e.g. Ribbon.
2. Validation from my point of view is better in Silverlight, you have ValidationSummary Control which is simplifying a lot of things, DescriptionViewer
3. Want to use different logging mechanism with WPF

In the worst case you will end up with just different XAML's for views and some places with code like that:

```
#if SILVERLIGHT
    //Code for silverlight
#else
    //Code for WPF
#endif
```